# How to add Content-Md5 Header to RestSharp file upload request?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, md5, restsharp, pre-signed-url

I am trying to upload a list of strings as a csv to a presigned URL in AWS S3.

I have successfully upload this using the default .NET HttpClient, but I am unable to use RestSharp RestClient to do the same thing.

The Error returned by AWS is: **BadDigest - The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.**

These are code sections I have been using. Both have the same inputs:

- `ids`: a list of strings
- `md5`: `byte[]`, calculated with `md5.ComputeHash()` in `System.Security.Cryptography` library
- `url`: presigned URL

Upload using HttpClient: (successful)

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms, new UTF8Encoding(false), 8192, true))
    {
        sw.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ids));
    }
    ms.Position = 0;

    var file = ms.ToArray();
    var content = new ByteArrayContent(file);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
    content.Headers.ContentLength = file.Length;
    content.Headers.ContentMD5 = md5;

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var result = client.PutAsync(url, content).Result;
    var response = result.Content.ReadAsString();
}
```

Upload using RestSharp: (failed - Bad Digest)

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms, new UTF8Encoding(false), 8192, true))
    {
        sw.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ids));
    }
    ms.Position = 0;

    var file = ms.ToArray();
    var md5Based64 = Convert.ToBase64String(md5).Replace("-", "");
    var options = new FileParameterOptions
    {
        DisableFilenameEncoding = true,
    };
    var uploadRequest = new RestRequest()
        .AddFile("", file, "", "text/csv", options)
        .AddOrUpdateHeader("Content-Md5", md5Based64)
        .AddOrUpdateHeader("Content-Length", file.Length)
        .AddOrUpdateHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");

    var restClient = new RestClient(
        new Uri(url), 
        configureSerialization: cfg =>
        {
            cfg.UseNewtonsoftJson();
        }, 
        useClientFactory: true
    );
    var response = restClient.ExecuteAsync(uploadRequest, Method.Put).Result;
}
```

I feel like the conversion between `md5` and `md5Based64` might be the key here or maybe manually adding header `AddOrUpdateHeader("Content-Md5", md5Based64)` is causing it to failed but I am not sure what else to do.

Any suggestions on how to fix this are welcomed. Let me know if you notice anything missing or want to be clarified.

Comment: Instead of:
`Convert.ToBase64String(md5).Replace("-", "");`
try this:
`BitConverter.ToString(md5).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();`

Comment: You could try to look at the request in wireshark for example and compare the two md5 headers, to see how they are diffrent. As Slepoyi mentioned it could already be the base64 encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RestSharp.AddFile` encodes your request as `multipart/form-data`, while your pre-signed URL and the hashing algorithm both expect raw file data in the request body.

Instead of `AddFile`, use [`AddStringBody`](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#addstringbody):

> If you have a pre-serialized payload like a JSON string, you can use AddStringBody to add it as a body parameter. You need to specify the content type, so the remote endpoint knows what to do with the request body.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I didn't follow your suggestion exactly (mostly because I don't know how to translate csv file into StringBody - or know if it's feasible; I am still learning), but it did point me toward the right direction. Instead, I ended up using `AddParameter("text/csv", file, ParameterType.RequestBody)` to bypass RestSharp default encoding.